# How to Store User Data to NOR Flash Memory using Xilinx ISE Impact?

Tags: flash-memory, xilinx-ise

I'm working with Spartan-6 FPGA and Winbond25Q64FV flash memory.
I want to store some data(which is a .txt file) onto the flash memory using Xilinx ISE Impact. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I'm Sharing my solution here in case it helps others and saves time.

To start, create a .mem file. The beginning of this file indicates the start address (started with @), followed by data entries positioned from that address onward. Each cell's content, in hexadecimal form should be separated by a space.

[image]

After that, follow the process of creating a PROM file in Xilinx ISE Impact.

[image]

Based on your flash memory follow these phases:

[image]

Following that, you'll be prompted to browse for the .mcs and .mem files. Upon selection, the .mem file will be linked to the .mcs main configuration file.